# Replace key name by its value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

```
 todo = {
"1.CoverLetterPage":"Hello",
    "3.JoiningDate":"Any Day",
    '4.Location':'Texas',
    '6.Leave':'AnyDay',
 };
```

I have called the list of keys in the list

```
done=[1.CoverLetterPage,4.Location,"3.JoiningDate,6.Leave]
```

What if i want to replace the values in the list 'done' by its value by typescript

Comment: Try `Object.values(todo)`

Comment: Can you clarify what you’re looking for? Object.keys(todo) will get your to the done array.

Comment: I have to replace the valuies in the done list by its value coming from todo list so thet my finally done list will look like this                                                                    done-["Hello",'Texas','Any Day','AnyDay']

Answer (score 3):

Use map function to obtain values from **todo** object and overwrite **done**.

```
this.done = this.done.map( v => this.todo[v] )
```

Also your done array values should be in string form with qoutes around them like below:

```
done=['1.CoverLetterPage','4.Location','3.JoiningDate','6.Leave']
```